# JavaScript: Callback Accessing another parameter

Tags: javascript, callback

In [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) it seems that a callback is accessing another parameter (without having to provide the argument again).

**Excerpt from the link above**

```
var SimplePropertyRetriever = {
    getPrototypeEnumerables: function(obj) {
        return this._getPropertyNames(obj, false, true, this._enumerable);
    },

    _enumerable: function(obj, prop) {
        return obj.propertyIsEnumerable(prop);
    },

    _getPropertyNames: function getAllPropertyNames(obj, iterateSelfBool, iteratePrototypeBool, includePropCb) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As seen:

- `this._enumerable` is passed to `_getPropertyNames`
- `_enumerable` accepts a parameter called `obj`
- `obj` is not explicitly passed down though, so it seems that when the callback is passed to `_getPropertyNames` it somehow accesses its first argument, which is `obj`

To test it, I tried the below, which did not work.

```
function myFunc2(para, callback) {
    console.log(`Para: ${para}`);
    callback();
}
myFunc2(42, (para) => console.log(para));
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Pass `para` -  "console.log(`Para: ${para}, callback: ${callback(para)}`);"

Comment: "which did not work": what were you expecting exactly and how does it not work? The callback function you pass to your call logs the param it is given, but you give it none when you call it: `callback();`. This `para` is not the same than in your callback defined in your call, you should distinct them to avoid confusion: `myFunc2(42, (x) => console.log(x));`

Comment: @gurvinder372 That's exactly my point. `this._enumerable` does not pass `obj` down. To my understanding, I would have written it as `this.enumerable(obj, prop)`

Comment: @Kaddath Yep, I know, which is why I don't get how the linked example work. `_enumerable` accesses `obj` in `_getPropertyNames`, when `obj` is never passed to it.

Comment: No, the tricky part here is that this line `return this._getPropertyNames(obj, false, true, this._enumerable);` doesn't call at all the `this._enumerable` function. It gives it as param to `this._getPropertyNames` so that `includePropCb` is now this function. It has yet to be called in `this._getPropertyNames` under that name (if needed). `this._getPropertyNames` already has `obj` as a parameter, so he can use it with the function if we want to.

Comment: Ah, damn, that's right. Thanks a lot @Kaddath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you understand **Closures** and **Variable Scopes** in JavaScript.

For the code snippet you mentioned above, since your callback needs an arg 'para' you can pass it and log it. If you don't want to pass it you can just add it to global object( 'window' object in case of browser).

*This is because your anonymous callback function expects 'para' variable first in it's own body, next it will try to search in it's parent's body which in this case is global object.*

For the below example,

```js
function myFunc2(para, callback) {
    window.para = para;
    console.log(`Para: ${para}`);
    callback();
}
myFunc2(42, () => console.log(para));
```

Comment: Thank you. General follow-up question here if I may: How come the callback does not have access to variables in `myFunc2`, when it gets executed inside that function? As we know, functions have access to variables in outer scopes (which for the callback include both the outer function, as well as the global scope).

Comment: It's absolutely true that "functions have access to variables in outer scopes", and this is valid if function is declared inside its outer function declaration and not while  invocation. So in your case the callback resides in global context while execution and not in "myFunc2". I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah, because scope is determined statically at compile-time, not run-time, and the execution only happens run-time?

Comment: I would like to call JavaScript an interpreted language ( this can be debated). I belive JavaScript follows "lexical scoping" so scope is decided by knowing where the variable sits physically.